# Manipulating factorials algebraically

Tags: factorial

Hi I was wondering how to prove (if possible) that $\frac{(n+2)!-(n+1)!}{(n+1)!-n!}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}$.

I am just going into calculus 2 so I’m sure there is a way to prove this I’ve just not learned it yet.

Comment: Remember that $\,(n+1)! = (n+1) \cdot n!\,$.

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate $a /cdot b$ where $a,b$ are any real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(n+2)!-(n+1)!}{(n+1)!-n!}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n!-(n+1)n!}{(n+1)n!-n!}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)-(n+1)}{n+1-1}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(n+2)!-(n+1)!}{(n+1)!-n!}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n!-(n+1)n!}{(n+1)n!-n!}$$
Factor out $(n+1)n!$ from numerator and $n!$ from denominator.
$$=\frac{(n+1)n!(n+2-1)}{n!(n+1-1)}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$$

So,
$$\frac{(n+2)!-(n+1)!}{(n+1)!-n!}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$$

Comment: Okay I understand thank you